# Restricting SSH Access at (HA)proxy on User

Tags: security, ssh, haproxy

I am setting up git ssh access via the internet.

The git server is hosted in a private subnet, with no SSH access publicly exposed. In order to provide access (through the public subnet), an HAproxy has been setup forwarding SSH access through to the backend git server from the internet.

I expect users to access git via a URL like:

```
ssh://git@my-git-server.example.com:8022/repopath.git
```

My HAProxy stanza looks like this:

```
my-git-server
    bind *:8022",
    mode tcp",
    server git 172.16.0.1:22 check port 22"
```

This works, and meets requirements, but has a security issue inherent in it - we are also exposing all other users on the git server. i.e. I can also connect to non-git users like this:

```
ssh://privateuser@my-git-server.example.com:8022
```

I would like to make sure that **only** the git user is exposed (i.e. it is not possible to access other users via the internet).

I would like to do this via the haproxy, if possible, but do not know how to change my haproxy rule to filter out requested URLs without "git@". 
If it is not possible in HAProxy, would appreciate suggestions on how to manage this via ssh-config on the git server.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe someone is still interested in this, even though I'm almost 4 years too late. As far as I know this is not possible with HAProxy. But it is easy to do this on the Git server in the sshd_config file if you still use the HAProxy server to connect to it from remote/internet.
Just add this at the end of the sshd_config file:

```
Match Address IP.OF.HAPROXY.SERVER
    AllowUsers git
```

That way only user git is allowed to login when traffic is coming from the IP of your HAProxy. Nevertheless before reloading sshd you might want to test your new sshd config with:

```
sshd -t
```